# How to get column index of clicked column of listview that hasn't listview item?

Tags: c#, winforms, listview

I have done this and it works fine :

```
private int getcolumn()
{
    Point mousePosition = base.PointToClient(Control.MousePosition);
    ListViewHitTestInfo hit = base.HitTest(mousePosition);   
    return hit.Item.SubItems.IndexOf(hit.SubItem); 
}
```

But works if in the listview there is at least one item.
My list is empty, so how can i get column index?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: you could do a conditional check to see if the item is empty or not.. or the SubItem in your case

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An empty list is going to return a null subitem.

However, while the example below is not very elegant, you can see how to use the Y position to determine which column the Y is associated with:

```
private int getcolumn()
{
    Point mousePosition = base.PointToClient(Control.MousePosition);
    switch(mousePosition.Y)
    {
        case mousePosition.Y >= 0 && mousePosition.Y <= base.Columns(0).Width:
            Return base.Columns(0).index
            break;
        case mousePosition.Y >= base.Columns(0).Width && mousePosition.Y <= base.Columns(1).Width:
            Return base.Columns(1).index
            break;
        case mousePosition.Y >= base.Columns(0).Width + base.Columns(1).Width && mousePosition.Y <= base.Columns(2).Width:
            Return base.Columns(2).index
            break;
        default:
            Return -1
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
private int getcolumn()
{
    Point mousePosition = base.PointToClient(Control.MousePosition);
    ListViewHitTestInfo hit = base.HitTest(mousePosition);   
    if Item.SubItems.Any()
    {
    return hit.Item.SubItems.IndexOf(hit.SubItem);
    }
    else
    {
    return -1; 
    }
}
```

Comment: Seems doesn't work, when there are not items hit item value null